# XCode: SIGABRT when uncaught exception arises

Tags: xcode

I am getting a SIGABRT on the following line

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

after stepping through the code for quite a while I found that the sigabrt happens right after

```
NSData *jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myDict
                                                  options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                    error:nil];
```

and then I figured out that I used an NSDate in one of the properties of the dict which aparently can't be serialized - and looking at the output console I also see the line:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSDate)'
```

so it's clear, I used an invalid argument there.

But what irritates me is that XCode stops with a signal:SIGABRT on the return UIApplicationMain line instead of showing an invalid argument exception on the line where I passed an invalid argument.

What is the reason for this behaviour?

I'm using XCode 5.0.2

Comment: This does not actually answer your question but you should use `[NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:myDict]` to see if you can convert the object to JSON and only try the conversion if this returns YES. Exceptions are generally not used as flow control in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add an *exception breakpoint* to stop closer to the issue.

See this [Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html).

Comment: but this breaks on every throw or every catch of an exception. I only want it to show me the proper line if an unhandled exception causes the app to crash

Comment: @user1282931 Not sure that makes sense.  It's not possible to know if an exception is "handled" until it hits `main()`, which is what's happening in your case.

Comment: but that's possible in other languages too... can't the IDE show where the exception that is not handled was thrown?

Comment: okay - thank you. Is there also a way to actually see what kind of exception is thrown when the exception breakpoint hits?